# Xero Transactions posted in a nominal account between two specific dates

Tags: .net, xero-api

Basically we are struggling to find APIs that can extract transactional data based on nominal codes. The only APIs available seem to call on Journals, Invoices and Bills separately. In other words, if I want to inquire about transactions posted in a nominal account between two specific dates, there doesn't appear to be one API call which will give me all transactions, instead I have to raise five calls to get the info (journals, invoices, bills, spent money, receive money).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Journal entry is created for every type of transaction in Xero. We are using this endpoint as the base of our system, and then supplementing these records (where necessary) with data from other endpoints depending on the [Source Type](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/Types#JournalSourceTypes) (e.g. Invoice, Bank Transaction, Manual Journal, etc).

In terms of querying based on date, you can use the If-Modified-Since header (see the Optional Parameters of the [Journals API documentation](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/journals). Unfortunately it doesn't seem like the Journals endpoint allows you to use Where parameters like other endpoints.